# How to keep following Endpoints as a property files in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

I have a requirement. for accomplish that i want to keep this end points as a property files in application property files.

**Create Endpoint,
http://35.240.228.219/services/create_common.php
{"activeStatus":200,"outputObject":{},"settingsObject":{},"connectToken":"","inputObject":{"filterCriteria":"news","sourceLink":"dtv"},"sessionId":815100,"userId":171}**

Delete Endpoint,

**http://35.240.228.219/services/delete_common.php
{"activeStatus":1,"outputObject":[],"settingsObject":[],"connectToken":"","inputObject":{"filterCriteria":"news","sourceLink":"dtv"},"sessionId":815100,"userId":171}**

Can anyone suggest me how to keep these kind of web endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In application.properties you can have below properties:

```
endpoint.create=http://35.240.228.219/services/create_common.php
endpoint.delete=http://35.240.228.219/services/delete_common.php
```

and from anywhere in your `controller/service/class` you can call them like this:

```
@Value("${endpoint.create}")
private String createEndPoint;

//use it anywhere..
```